# sed option to preserve file times during a find/replace?

Tags: linux, macos, sed, timestamp

I'm trying to modify some Autotool files because a project is not honoring my `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`. I located some areas where I could likely make the change with a `grep` for `libtool: link`. When I tweaked the Autotool files:

```
$ sed -i "" 's|$CC -dynamiclib|$CC -dynamiclib -force_cpusubtype_ALL|g' configure configure.ac
```

It resulted in:

```
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.14' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
```

`touch -t 19700101 configure.ac` did not resolve the issue.

I'm on an old OS X system, and it does not have the tools desired by the tools. I grepped the [`sed(1)` man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed), but I don't see an option to preserve file times.

How do I instruct `sed` to preserve the file times?

Comment: `sed -i '.bak' ` would I think not preserve the file but back it up. But  how about sed without -i and use redirect  `sed "s/a/b/" >file.b`    or just `cat file1|sed "s/a/b/"`  or   `sed "s/a/b/" file.a`  They dump to screen.  Only the sed -i will overwrite the original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sed`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html) is unlikely to do that in any implementation.  The command

```
touch -t 19700101 configure.ac
```

tells [`touch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/touch.1.html) to set the timestamp to a bogus date (because only 8 digits are given) using

- *MM* = 19
- *DD* = 70
- *hh* = 01
- *mm* = 01

You probably intended

```
touch -t 197001010000 configure.ac
```

(8 digits for 19700101, plus 4 more digits for 0000), although you can run into timezone problems with that.  In any case, it is unlikely that resetting a file's timestamp so far back is necessary.  I would simply reset it to the original value.

For example (I usually do this with [cpd](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:cpd)), one could write a script to copy the timestamp from the original file to the edited file.  Here is a sample script which works for OSX:

```
#!/bin/sh
usage() {
    echo "usage: $0 source target" >&2
    exit 1
}

[ $# = 2 ] || usage

[ -L "$1" ] && usage
[ -L "$2" ] && usage

[ -f "$1" ] || usage
[ -f "$2" ] || usage

SOURCE=$(stat -t "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S" -f "%Sm" "$1")
ls -l $2
touch -t "$SOURCE" "$2"
ls -l $2
```

Interestingly enough (the command-line `stat` is *not* standardized), the OSX version of [`stat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) is more suited to this particular application than the Linux [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html).  For Linux, one might do something similar by obtaining the timestamp from an `ls -l` listing, and using the non-standard `-d` option of [`touch`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html) to apply the timestamp.

Comment: Hmmm.... According to the man page I am looking at: `touch [-A [-][[hh]mm]SS] [-acfhm] [-r file] [-t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]]`. I (think) I provided the `CC`, `YY`, `MM` and `DD`.

Comment: CC and YY are optional, and not used at all of there are only 8 digits. That is what the square brackets denote.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mix of `sed -i` and `touch`, to preserve the initial timestamp. For example:

```
file=file-to-edit

sed -i .bak 's|...' "$file"
touch -r "$file.bak" "$file"
# rm "$file.bak"
```